# Giving public access to rethinkdb's dashboard when installed on Docker

Tags: docker, curl, port, rethinkdb

rethinkdb:latest is installed and running on Docker

```
docker run -d --net rethinkdb-net -p 5000:8080 --expose 5000 --name rethinkdb-stable2 rethinkdb:latest
```

Using curl, I can see the dashboard is running, also if I use -p 80:8080, I can see it when visiting the IP. I've also tried opening the port like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:8080
```

Which gives the result

```
DNAT   tcp  --  anywhere   anywhere   tcp dpt:5000 to:172.18.0.2:8080
```

The iptables elements were unnecessary for curl to see the site, but whatever I do I can only see the site at the IP:80, but not IP:5000 (I need :80 for my web app).

I'm on an Debian 8, cloud instance.

Comment: Can you try removing the iptable rule?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it doesn't change anything. I've also reset it.

Answer (score 1):

As it probably isn't a good idea to do this anyway, I'm using SSH -L :5000 to see the admin interface.